# Error while using lightning Icon (Unknown token: 'undefined'. Are you missing a tokens file or declaration?)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, icon

I am using lightning:icon tag to display icon in my lightning component. Some icons are working fine and some are throwing error.Below is the code which is not working.

```
<lightning:icon iconName="Utility:expand_alt" class="slds-icon slds-icon_small" size="small" alternativeText="Expand"/>
<lightning:icon iconName="Utility:contract_alt" class="slds-icon slds-icon_small" size="small" alternativeText="Contract"/>
```

**Error:**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because Javascript is case sensitive and it will be "utility" not "Utility"

```
<lightning:icon iconName="utility:expand_alt" class="slds-icon slds-icon_small" size="small" alternativeText="Expand"/>
<lightning:icon iconName="utility:contract_alt" class="slds-icon slds-icon_small" size="small" alternativeText="Contract"/>
```

Comment: Works,I did silly mistake. Thank you.